# Exchange part of view using TornadoFX

Tags: user-interface, kotlin, view, tornadofx

I'm working on a Fitness App and try to create something like a menubar which exchanges the container to the right depending on the currently selected menu item. The solution I've come up with until now is that I derive every view that is bound to a menu item from the main view and exchange the container using the `replaceWith<ExcerciseEditor>()` function. It works but I figure there must be a better solution to  this.

```
// MainView.kt

open class MainView : View("Fit App"){
    protected val container: StackPane by fxid()
    override val root: AnchorPane by fxml("/view/MainView.fxml")

    fun createExercise(){
        replaceWith<ExerciseEditor>()
    }

    // [...]
}

// ExerciseEditor.kt

class ExerciseEditor : MainView(){

    init {
        container.children += loadFXML<AnchorPane>("/view/ExerciseEditor.fxml")
    }

    // [...]
}
```

The app looks like this. The root of this view is a HBox containing two panes: to the left the menu bar and to the right a stack pane containing the other views.

[image: Final Result]

Comment: Why is `ExcerciseEditor` a child of the main view? Wouldn't that unnecessarily expose the main view, and give the editor an give it a large size? Also, what's the point of using a stackpane if you're just going to replace the views anyways?

Comment: It is a child of main view because I didn't really know how else I could achieve the relation between editor and main having the same menubar etc. Which container would you suggest instead?

Comment: I don't think the menu bar should be replicated at all. The way I would go is to have the main view root be a border pane, with the left side hold the menubar, and the center have something simple like an HBox (you can use a plain pane but hbox/vboxs naturally fill out its parent). The menubar buttons then activate a function that uses `find<CertainView>().root`, clears the children of the content-holding pane, and adds the new root in. There may be more elegant solutions, but this is similar to what I've done and it's simple. From my experience, this way still activates `onDock`/`onUndock`.

Comment: One last thing: If the child views need to activate/communicate something outside itself, then using TornadoFX's dependency injection can be used to access a common `ViewModel` or `Controller`: https://edvin.gitbooks.io/tornadofx-guide/content/part2/Dependency%20Injection.html. Or, if you want to decouple even more, you can use the fire/subscribe method of the `EventBus` found here: https://edvin.gitbooks.io/tornadofx-guide/content/part2/EventBus.html

Comment: Thanks a lot @JCamacho I was able to fix it that way